# Change the color of an already existing label in Tcl/Tk

Tags: label, tcl, tk-toolkit

I have a status bar which is a label connected to a variable:

```
label .main_frame.status_bar.status_label -textvariable _DB(status_text)
```

I want to change the color of the text each time I get an error, meaning when the status bar shows an error, the text should be red, when later it shows normal status, it should change back to black. How do I change the `-foreground` property of the label "on the fly"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can reconfigure any Tk widget property live by calling the widget `configure` procedure. In this case:

```
.main_frame.status_bar.status_label configure -foreground $new_colour
```

Answer (score 7):

```
$label configure -fg $color
```

or

```
$label configure -foreground $color
```

Run `$label configure` in an interactive wish shell to see all the options you can change.

P.S.
I should add that IMO this approach to error reporting is flawed. Showing non-critical *warnings* this way is okay, but errors should be reported more aggressively.